# Decide the entity type of entity framework query dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have a `DbContext` sub class that looks like

```
public partial class DBEntities : DbContext
{ ...//More to come }
```

and in this class I have 2 `DbSet` instances:

```
public DbSet<Config> Config { get; set; }
public DbSet<Parameters> Parameters { get; set; }
```

that look like:

```
public partial class Config
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Override { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

AND

```
public partial class Parameters
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
    public float AzValue_rad { get; set; }
    public float E_rad { get; set; }
    public float N_rad { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say I want to have a configuration xml that will encode saved queries.

How can I do that and keep my type strength?

e.g.

How can I encode the query

```
using (var db = new DBEntities())
{
     var query = from floatTag in db.Config
                 select floatTag;
                 where floatTag.Name = "SOME_VALUE" 
}
```

**EDIT:**

I am developing an application that allows the user to define triggers, for example, when a certain field in the DB equals a certain value.

I want to save those triggers, so they would allow me to remember them the next time my app is loaded. Meaning I want to save the database, table and value the trigger deifnes (i.e DBEntities,Config,"SOME_VALUE")

Then, I want to de-serialize  those triggers, and then from code, decode the correct Db context and entity so I could re-execute that query.

Comment: please explain `encode saved queries`. In conjunction with title

Comment: There are millions of ways to do this. Firstly, why do you want to save queries in an XML file? What kind of queries do you want to encode. I doubt that you want to develop a full XML equivalent of LINQ.